# jQuery filtering list without hiding parents

Tags: jquery, search, filtering

I have a list like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="folder">Foder A</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1A</li>
    <li>Item 2A</li>
    <li>Item 3A</li>     
  </ul>
  <li class="folder">Foder B</li>
  <ul>
    <li class="folder">Sub-Foder C</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1C</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Item 1B</li>
    <li>Item 2B</li>
    <li>Item 3B</li>     
  </ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

And this "search" script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[type='search']").keyup(function() {
  var filter = $(this).val();
  $("ul li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
      $(this).hide();
      }
    else {
      $(this).show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

But it is filtering all the `<li>s` and of course hiding even "folders".

How to keep showing parental `<li class="folder">` which contain search results?

Comment: You can get the direct children of the top level ul element and then hide all others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your initial code a little bit and I think I got the desired use case now. But first let's briefly take a look what I changed.

1. Instead of iterating over all `li` elements on every `keyup`, I used `$('ul li').toArray()` to get an Array of NodeElements when the document is ready.
2. Initially we hide everything on `keyup`
3. As you can see, I've used a little bit different approach for filtering out the matched values. Since my list is an Array now, I'm using the `filter` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) function which will return a new Array based of NodeElements which are matching the condition `entry.innerText.includes(value)`([MDN - String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)).
4. Afterwards, I iterate over the results Array and apply `show()` to each entry AND I'm also using `parentsUntil('.top-level')` (I added the class `top-level` to the most top `<ul>` element) to get the ancestors of my current entry (the one which matches the search) and I target the immediately preceding `li` element of those ancestors by using `prev(...)` ([jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)). Finally I apply `show(...)` on those elements.

The exact definition of `parentsUntil(...)` is defined as following:

> Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object.
>
> [Source](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/)

**SNIPPET**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var list = $('ul li').toArray();

  $("input[type='search']").keyup(function() {
    $('ul li').hide();
    var value = $(this).val();

    var result = list.filter(function(entry) {
      return entry.innerText.includes(value);
    });

    result.forEach(function(entry) {
      $(entry).show().parentsUntil('.top-level').prev('li').show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" />
<ul class="top-level">
  <li class="folder">Foder A</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1A</li>
    <li>Item 2A</li>
    <li>Item 3A</li>
  </ul>
  <li class="folder">Foder B</li>
  <ul>
    <li class="folder">Sub-Foder C</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1C</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Item 1B</li>
    <li>Item 2B</li>
    <li>Item 3B</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```